# Update a column in first table with values in second table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two tables - Order Table and Sub Order Table

Order Table

```
Order_Id |Customer |Status
--------------------------
101      Abc      1
102      xyz      1
```

Sub Order Table

```
Sub_Order_Id | Order_Id    | Sub_order_status
---------------------------------------
10101          101         2
10102          101         2
10103          101         1
10201          102         1
```

I need to update the order table status =2, if all the sub order id' status =2

Get orderid 101 if all its sub order status =2

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
update o
set status = 2
from order o
where not exists (
  select 1 from suborder
  where order_id = o.order_id and sub_order_status <> 2
)
```

This syntax will work for SQL Server.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73cda9eb4e8b5909af16b4d6eb52090d).
If you only need to select the orders:

```
select o.* 
from [order] o 
where not exists (
  select 1 from suborder
  where order_id = o.order_id and sub_order_status <> 2
)
```

Comment: not working..status got updated to  2..for all entries

Comment: Thanks for your response..Could you please change the sub order status to 1 for sub order id 10103 and execute the statement

Comment: @Sara If I change to 1 it will **not** be updated because **not all** sub_order_status will be 2.

Comment: how to write a select statement for  this, to select order id from order table if all its sub order status = 2..thanks

Answer (score 0):

you try by using corelated subquery

```
UPDATE Order t
SET    Status = 2
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   SubOrder  s
                   WHERE  s.Order_Id = t.Order_Id 
                   and Sub_order_status=2
                   group by s.Order_Id
                   having sum(Sub_order_status)%count(*)=0
                     );
```

Comment: I need to select the order id only if all the sub order status = 2

Comment: @Sara yes this sum(Sub_order_status)%count(*)=0 condition will ensure that

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want:

```
UPDATE o
    SET o.[Status] = 2
FROM
[order] o
WHERE o.Order_Id IN (
    SELECT Order_Id
    FROM [sub_order]
    GROUP BY Order_Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN Sub_order_status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) )
```